# HSSFWorkbook java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No more than 3 rules may be specified

Tags: java, apache-poi

I got this exception while instantiating an HSSFWorkbokk object and really I do not understand what is the problem.

I do not understand the exception message in anyway

The code is very simple.

```
private HSSFWorkbook getXLWorkbook(MultipartFile file) throws IOException{
    InputStream inputStream = file.getInputStream();
    HSSFWorkbook xlWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    return xlWorkbook;
}
```

and the exception is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No more than 3 rules may be specified
at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.CFRecordsAggregate.<init>(CFRecordsAggregate.java:58)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.CFRecordsAggregate.createCFAggregate(CFRecordsAggregate.java:96)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.aggregates.ConditionalFormattingTable.<init>(ConditionalFormattingTable.java:49)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Sheet.<init>(Sheet.java:176)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Sheet.createSheet(Sheet.java:161)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:282)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:196)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:312)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:293)
at net.mis.financialstatement.service.FinancialStatementServiceImpl.getXLWorkbook(FinancialStatementServiceImpl.java:186)
at net.mis.financialstatement.service.FinancialStatementServiceImpl.updateXlsSheetKeys(FinancialStatementServiceImpl.java:386)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy158.updateXlsSheetKeys(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy7.updateXlsSheetKeys(Unknown Source)
at net.mis.financialstatement.web.admin.controller.FinancialStatementUpdateSheetAdminController.submitFinancialStatementUpdateXlsSheetForm(FinancialStatementUpdateSheetAdminController.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:560)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:710)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.edc.i18n.web.SiteLanguageFilter.doFilter(SiteLanguageFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at com.edc.core.concurrent.web.CleanThreadLocalUserSessionFilter.doFilter(CleanThreadLocalUserSessionFilter.java:36)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:378)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
at org.springframework.security.intercept.web.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilterHttp(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:101)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.providers.anonymous.AnonymousProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AnonymousProcessingFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.rememberme.RememberMeProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(RememberMeProcessingFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:277)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy148.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.ui.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilterHttp(LogoutFilter.java:89)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilterHttp(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:235)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:116)
at org.springframework.security.ui.SpringSecurityFilter.doFilter(SpringSecurityFilter.java:53)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:390)
at org.springframework.security.util.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:175)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:164)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:141)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:90)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:417)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Answer (score 7):

This may be a clue: 4th line in stack trace includes `ConditionalFormattingTable` - in (older versions of?) Excel we can define a maximum of three rules for condintional formatting of cells and this number corresponds to your error message.

Answer (score 1):

**Case Scenario layout**

[HSSFWorkbook object](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFWorkbook.html) is the interface to the opening **pre-2007/2010** Excel files.

In [this blog post from excel support group](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-flexible-effective-conditional-formats-in-excel-2007-HA010217629.aspx) It states:

> In previous versions of Excel, you could have a maximum of three conditional formats. There's no such limit in Office Excel 2007; you may have as many conditional formats as you like.

- When opening an Excel Workbook the constructors cascade filling the object with all that is available in the workbook, including any conditional formatting defined.
- amoung others a ConditionalFormattingTable is created which is populated with CFRecordsAggregates.
- Each Conditional Format Record contains a set of Rules.
- Because **pre-2007/2010** Excel files were limited to 3 rules, the library object is also limited to 3. The [CFRecordsAggregate class](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/record/aggregates/CFRecordsAggregate.html) states in its description:

  > CFRecordsAggregate - aggregates Conditional Formatting records CFHeaderRecord and number of **up to three CFRuleRecord records** together to simplify access to them.

So, if you have an excel file that was made by Excel 2003 and you are opening it with HSSFWorkbook you should have no problem.

It is however possible to **create a file in Excel 2007, Excel 2010, LibreOffice Calc, etc... with more than 3 rules per cell** and then **Save it in the Excel 2003 format** , preserving those defined rules.

When POI detects the pre 2007 Excel format, it opens it with HSSFWorkbook and all the rest... and when it bumps into more than 3 rules defined it throws an exception.

---

** Example Files **

- Causes Exception to be thrown

  - [Multi-Conditional-Formatting Rules saved as Old Excel Format XLS](http://www.filedropper.com/mcfrsaxls)
- Properly Saved Excel File

  - [Multi-Conditional-Formatting Rules saved as New Excel Format XLSX](http://www.filedropper.com/mcfrsaxlsx)

---

** Solution **

- Save the file in Excel 2007/2010 XML (xlsx) format.
- make sure you have are using the following libraries.

  - poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
  - poi-ooxml-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
  - xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
  - dom4j-1.6.1.jar
  - poi-ooxml-schemas-3.10-FINAL-20140208.jar
- Open the workbook as such `Workbook myWorkbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(new File(myFilePath)));`

---

- Alternative work around*

  1. open the excel file with LibreOffice Calc for example.
  2. Menu --> Format --> Conditional Formatting --> Manage.
  3. A dialog window with a list of Conditional Formatting Records
  4. Select one and click on Edit...
  5. A dialog pops up with the Condition List (i.e. CFRuleRecords)
  6. If there are more than 3 Conditions defined in a record, that is where it is crashing our program.
  7. Compact the rules to be less than 3 per record.

     - If there are only 3 different styles that will need to be applied we can merge 2 or more conditions by using Formulas.
     - If this is not the case I would attempt to spread out the rules into different records applied over the same ranges.
     - If this still doesn't prove successful, try to move the conditional formatting to some macros.

---

I have reported this as a [Bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56482) already.

Comment: Do you have an Excel produced file that shows up the problem? If so, you best bet is to [report a bug to Apache POI](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/buglist.cgi?product=POI) and upload the valid excel file to the bug which shows the problem

Comment: (The comments at the top of `CFRecordsAggregate` states *Excel allows up to 3 conditional formating rules*, so there's clearly something different going on with your file)

Comment: @Gagravarr, Thanks for your comments. [In this blog post from excel support group](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-flexible-effective-conditional-formats-in-excel-2007-HA010217629.aspx) It states: In previous versions of Excel, you could have a maximum of three conditional formats. There’s no such limit in Office Excel 2007; you may have as many conditional formats as you like. ... I will update the answer with link to an excel sheet which produces this error and file a bug report.

Comment: Ah ha, another file format difference! Would be best if you could contribute your file to the project, so that it can be included in a unit test for a future fix

Comment: I just found out that actually the library works if everything is as expected, but reality is full of surprises. For the case where a sheet with more than 3 rules per cell has been saved in the old excel format the library fails...Such a sheet would normally be saved in the new Excel XML format...  will update answer. @Gagravarr Thanks for inspiring me to find the answer :)

Comment: Try again with tonight's nightly build :)